# Python: how to let python get the "zero"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zero

here is my code:

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

file = "test.txt"

st = StanfordNERTagger("english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz")
usr_input = input("Enter sentence, or just hit ENTER to quit: ")
tagged = st.tag(word_tokenize(usr_input))
result = None
print(tagged)
print(list(e1 for e1,e2 in tagged))
with open(file, "r") as read_file:
    for elem in tagged:
        print(elem[0])
        print(elem[-1])
        if elem[-1] == "0":
            print("null")
        else:
            print("yes")
```

And then this is my output:

```
Enter sentence, or just hit ENTER to quit: left-wing
[('left-wing', 'O')]
['left-wing']
left-wing
O
yes
```

Process finished with exit code 0

My question is: why cannot python find/read the value of zero?
I tried with "0", '0', {0}.. and all of them didn't really help.

Thank you so much!

Comment: So your're input is `left-wing` and it don't get the null-terminating zero or `left-wing 0` and it don't get the string 0?

Comment: Your zero isn't a 0 (zero) but an O (capital O)

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge Yes you are right! ;) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have letter 'O' in your record rather than digit '0'